# Rails, S3, Paperclip- Uploads are being logged by S3 but not in bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am working on a Rails app where I want people to be able to upload their photos into a feed. I am trying to integrate this in with S3 and paperclip. Right now every time someone has uploaded a photo it shows a broken image and when I inspect the element I get a missing.png.

Naturally, I went to check the s3 bucket to see if they were getting there. The bucket was empty but the logs had an event for every time I tried to upload a photo.

I have been messing around trying to figure this out for a day now so any help you can give me will be super helpful. Here is my implementation so far:

**in _photo.html.erb:**

```
    <%= image_tag @feed_item.photo.url %>
```

in users/show.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for @feed_item, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :photo %>
    <%= form.file_field :photo %>
    <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
```

**in config/s3.yml**

```
    access_key_id: 'some_key_id',
    secret_access_key: 'some_access_key'
```

**in models/feed_item.rb**

```
    attr_accessible :data, :feed_item_points_count, :user_id, :photo
    has_attached_file :photo
```

**in Gemfile**

```
    gem 'paperclip'
    gem 'aws-sdk'
```

**in Migration file**

```
class AddPhotosToFeedItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
  add_attachment :feed_items, :photo
 end

 def self.down
  remove_attachment :feed_items, :photo
 end
end
```

Thanks! Any help you can offer would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass storage option as :s3

```
eg:
has_attached_file :photo
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :server => 'mystore.amazonaws.com',
                  :bucket => BUCKET_NAME,
                  :path => "photos/:id/:styles",
                  :s3_credentials => {:access_key_id => 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM',
                                      :secret_access_key => 'ukyto8347trocq347to8764ro3'}
```

Comment: I just tried the implementation above with my aws information and I am still having the same issue. Any other idea on what it could be?

Comment: Have you created the bucket in amazon?